# Django.auth.authenticate not authenticating user

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-users

I am creating an app, and I am trying to manually create the login page so I can add some things that I can't add using the default Django authentication pages. This is what my view looks like:

```
def logIn(request):
    formClass = LogInForm
    template = "login.html"
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth.authenticate(username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password"])
        return redirect("/")
    
    return render(request, template, {
        "form" : formClass
    })
```

But, when I print out the user's id after logging in, it returns `none`. Does somebody know what is going on?

Comment: the title of your question and the content appear to be different questions? is there a mixup?

Comment: oops- i forgot to change it. i was writing a draft of something else...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

authenticate only check usercredentails. For creating a user session you need to call login function.
Import login function and modify the code like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def logIn(request):
    formClass = LogInForm
    template = "login.html"
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        user  = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST["username"], password=request.POST["password"])
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
    
    return render(request, template, {
        "form" : formClass
    })
```